# Getting 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> to List<Map<String,String>>' while instantiating a list of maps

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, hashmap, linkedhashmap

```
List<Map<String, String>> recordMapList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

The above line gives the error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList> to List>

But the issue goes away if use HashMap instead of Map in the left hand side.
Could someone tell me why this happens.
I need to have the left hand side to contain Map as I might be using the same variable to assign LinkedHashMap in the righ side like,

```
List<Map<String, String>> recordMapList = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap <String,String>>();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `ArrayList` is a sub class of `List`, and `HashMap` is a subclass of `Map`, an `List<HashMap>` is NOT a subclass of `List<Map>`. Similarly you cannot cast a `List<HashMap>` to a `List<Map>`. If we could, it would mean we could add let's say a `TreeMap` to our `List<Map>`, and then cast it to a `List<HashMap>`, thus violating the original contract of the `List<HashMap>`.

Personally I would just use a diamond operator (Java 7+) if the `recordMapList`-instance is immediately created:

```
List<Map<String, String>> recordMapList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And if it's created elsewhere only the `List` can be an `ArrayList`, but the rest would be the same. (NOTE: You could of course still use the diamond operator here as well, but if creating the instance and the actual field are separated, I personally prefer to use the types so it's instantly clear what type goes into the list, without jumping to the actual field in the code.)

```
List<Map<String, String>> recordMapList;
...
recordMapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

In both cases you can add your `HashMap<String, String>` instances to the `recordMapList`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is `List<HashMap>` is not the sub class of `List<Map>`

Solution, you do not need declare it as:

```
List<Map<String, String>> recordMapList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

you can declare it as:

```
List<Map<String, String>> recordMapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
```

and then put `HashMap` into the `recordMapList`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you avoid instantiating a list with a given generic type, ie:

```
List<Map<String, String>> recordMapList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is the convention of generic assignment from Java 7 onwards (from this version onwards generic types of assigned collection are inferred via the declared type). Why? Since the declared type of the list values has already been explicitly stated when declaring the generic list variable. The values are instances of the map interface and will be provided in the code implementation.

When accessing the list values what matters is the interface used (`Map`), and not its implementation (`HashMap`). This way, if the `Map` implementation is replaced, there will be no need to change the assigned value of `recordMapList`.

See the following example (which shows how the list is not bound by an implementation of `Map`):

```
List<Map<String,String>> recordMapList = new ArrayList<>(); // Declaration + Assignment
recordMapList.add(new HashMap<>()); // Add a first implementation of Map
recordMapList.add(new TreeMap<>()); // Add a second implementation of Map
```

Reference:

- [Java collections and generics best practices (third best practice)](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/18-java-collections-and-generics-best-practices)

Bonus:

- [A nice overview of collections in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-in-java-2/)